What is this geometrical convergence?
CONTEXT
The icosahedron is one of the convex uniform polyhedra. It has 12 vertices.
PROPOSITION
Take any vertex on the icosahedron, draw a vector from this vertex to the center of the icosahedron and name it the in-vector. You can draw an out-vector for each of the 12 vertices (back to the origin or towards any of the 11 other vertices).

When oriented (with an oriented pentagon in a plane perpendicular to the vector), these bi-vectors can be used to create helixes. From a single icosahedron, a tree of 12 helixes can be created, stacking icosahedrons in respect with the chosen bi-vector. Some bi-vectors create loops, some create helixes of various length.

Oriented Out-Vectors can be projected for each stacked icosahedron. Since we are drawing imaginary lines from different points in stacked helixes, when the size of these stacks becomes negligeable compared to the length of the lines (ie higher projection ratio) the projected vectors are converging to the surface of a sphere, never being exactly on this surface (hence converging).

These lines form segments bundles, in the shape of propeller blades, which are twisted at first, but the larger the projection, the less twisted relative to each other they are. The blades untwist to converge to a conic shape.

At the surface of the quasi-sphere, with a graphical simulation, we can measure the distance between segments inside a bundle, and the distance between the last segment of a bundle and the fisrt segment of the consecutive bundle. The ratio of these values converges, depending on the bi-vector angular orientation, to values with a structure similar to that of metallic numbers (ie they are ratios in the form $\frac{x+1}{x}$ or $\frac{x+2}{x+1}$ with $x \in ]0;1[$ and $x \in$ $\R$).
I created an animation here, it helps understanding better than still captures.
QUESTION
What is this convergence ? Can it be calculated ?

See publication "Sphere packing helices and the polytope {3,3,5}".
